# Web page isn't getting responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, web, responsive-design

I want to make my web page responsive. It works till 320px, but when I reduce the size of the screen furthermore, it doesn't work at all, and only half of the content gets visible.

Here's the required code

HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img
                src="assets/img/profile.png"
                height="520"
                width="500"
                hspace="20"
                class="responsive"
            />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p>
                Lorem Khaled Ipsum is a major key to success. To succeed you must
                believe. When you believe, you will succeed. Mogul talk. Find peace,
                life is like a water fall, you’ve gotta flow. Lion! Fan luv. Eliptical
                talk.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.responsive {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
}

img {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .nav-menu {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    .nav-toggle:hover {
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    .nav-toggle span {
        background-color: #dfdfdf;
    }

    .nav-toggle span:hover {
        background-color: #fff;
    }
}
```

It works fine till around 320px: 
[image]

But after further reducing it to less than 320px, the image doesn't fits the screen: 
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I did a test with the code you provided and it seems to work fine. I used bootstrap 4 CDN. Correction. it works on Firefox, not in Chrome.

Comment: It's interesting, because I just tested it in Chrome and it works here too: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ErqRXe

Comment: @JaydeepBorkar What's the effect you want to achieve? Can you include a screen capture of the problem?

Comment: yep, I had a typo on the viewport. I corrected it and it seems to be fine too.

Comment: @amedina I have added the screenshots of the problem, please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I have done:

I removed the `img` and `.responsive` styles and I used the Bootstrap `.img-fluid` class (check it [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/)):

```css
/* Deleted, because it isn't relevant anymore. */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1150" class="img-fluid" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>
          Lorem Khaled Ipsum is a major key to success. To succeed you must believe. When you believe, you will succeed. Mogul talk. Find peace, life is like a water fall, you’ve gotta flow. Lion! Fan luv. Eliptical talk.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I was trying it here on my computer. The image is 1150px wide, but the viewport is only 300px wide. The image adapts perfectly:

[image]

Hope it helps.